# String cutting until to k'th char without cutting a word in the middle

Tags: c++, string

Given a string and a number k, cut the string so the string length <= k and the cutting won't split a word or make the new string finish with space.

For example: "good morning everybody" with k = 15 will return "good morning".

This is my code

```
int main() {
    string str = "good morning everybody";
    int k = 15,i;
    for (i = k; i > 0; i--)
        if(str[i] == ' ' && (str[i-1] >= 'a' && str[i-1] <= 'z'))
            break;

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        cout << str[j];

    return 0;
}
```

but I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing that using regex or other C++ tricks. (I'm coming from Python world).

Comment: If your code works well and there is no issue, please consider posting the question at [codereview.se].

Comment: I will. Thank you

Comment: Hi, this is a problem solving website. If your code works then it is not worth of a question here. If you have specific questions  then you could ask. General like "I'm wondering if there is a better way", or "What should I do" would not be answered here.

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` has a member function `find_last_of` that finds the last occurrence of a character (or one of some characters) in it. Using that, you could write your function like this:

```
std::string cut(std::string const & s, std::size_t k)
{
  std::size_t pos = s.find_last_of(' ', k); // looks only in [s, s+k)
  return s.substr(0, pos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex in you can do it like this:

```
"^.{14}[\s]*[^\s]+"
```

In C++ you can use `std::format`, `std::regex` etc

Answer (score 0):

I am not encouraging to do this via regex, But you may try this with this regex:

```
^\b[\w ]{0,14}(?=\w(?=\s)).
```

[Try this here](https://regex101.com/r/Go4YuO/1)

Please note that if Your boundary is N then you should use N-1 in the regex. So If N is 15 then it should be used as 14 in the regex/